# Seeming contradiction of the tertium non datur principle through a logic problem

Tags: logic, paradoxes

The problem is as follows.

There is a group of three people (A,B,C) who are perfect logicians, and A is a thief.
We say that a person recognises another one if the former knows whether the latter is a thief or not.
Every logician knows that ther is only one thief in the group and that the others are perfect logicians as well.
Moreover every logician can ask another one if the latter recognices the other two, and the answer will always be sincere (yet they cannot know if the other logicians have already asked questions because, say, they are in different rooms and they communicate through sms).

Eg. If B knows that A is a thief then he also knows that C is not (from the first rule), and furthermore, now A and C know that B has recognised A and C.

Now, A, being the thief, surely knows that B and C are not thief.
So B and C know that A has recognised B and C.

The question is: if one person recognises everyone, can we infer that this person is a thief?

Well, if we can, then B would recognise A and C but then C would infer that B is a thief, a contradiction.
Yet, if we cannot, the only person who could recognise everyone else would be the thief so you could actually infer that this person is a thief, another contradiction.

Does this contradiction imply that we can't say if the statement "A recognises B and C" implies "A is a thief"?

Comment: There has to be a sequence to the deductions.  That is to say, $A$ must somehow reveal that he has recognized $B,C$ and only then can subsequent deductions be made.  You could formalize this by saying something like "each hour on the hour everyone gets in a room an simultaneously holds up a sign saying whom they have recognized." under this scheme, only $A$ announces anything on the first hour, but all three do at the second.

Comment: That's a good point but suppose they're all in different rooms and as before they can ask (by an sms for example) that question to one person at a time, in this case they wouldn't know if someone else had already asked any question, what would happen then?

Comment: Then $B,C$ would have no basis for making any deductions at all.

Comment: So WE can say that they can't make any deduction but they could never conclide that they can't make any deduction, as otherwise they would deduce that the only one who recognices the other two is the thief. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand your point.  If $B,C$ have no information, they can not deduce anything. If they are eventually given information, that might change.

Comment: I try to be clearer: my point is that $B, C $ cannot even only deduce that they can't deduce anything, because that would lead to a contradiction. Say the logicians are computers, they could never stop and conclude they can't deduce anything, they would just run forever, am I right in saying that?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Well, I mean if they conclude that they cannot deduce anything then they would know that the only one who recognises the other two would be the thief. Indeed, it seems to me that they have a crucial information, that the other non-thief will conclude the same things as the first does (being both perfect logicians)

Comment: They already knew that.  I don't understand what you are getting at.  Everybody knows before they start that the one who recognizes the other two is the thief.  That is obvious.  If they get no more information, then this is as far as they can go.  There is no mystery here, let alone any sort of paradox.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why that is obvious, suppose you are B, and you ask A if he recognises the other two, he'll say he does, but then  B could'nt know if A is the thief or he's only a non-thief who has already made the same deduction that B himself is making.

Comment: In that situation, $B$ can not deduce anything.  So what?

Comment: Deductions require information.  In order to state a coherent problem you need to be clear about what information is available to whom.  It is perfectly possible that one player has more information than another.  That happens all the time.

Comment: I'm not saying that this problem is extraordinary, I'm just surprised that B cannot even deduce that he cannot deduce anything, and I'm asking if this is true. And when I say they are all logicians I also mean they all conclude the same things from the same premises

Comment: Sorry, this is nonsense.  Of course $B$ can deduce that he is unable to determine the thief.  He can do so by exhibiting a logically possible state of the world in which $A$ is the thief, and one in which he is not.  But, enough.  I don't believe I am helping here, so I will stop commenting.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, thank you for your time nontheless

Comment: @lulu: I think there's a genuine problem here -- does my answer make sense to you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Perhaps I am being obtuse, but this all seems to me to come down to incomplete knowledge.  If I have no idea what communication may or may not have taken place between the other two, then, as you remark, I can make no deductions based on my hearing "I know the answer" from someone else.  Of course, hearing "I don't know the answer" is always informative.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @lulu: I think you're missing that if you can infer that the _other_ guy wouldn't be able to make deductions due to _his_ lack of knowledge, then suddenly _you_ can make a deduction after all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Well, I'm still not getting it.  It seems to me that so long as the rules are clear there is no confusion. To be sure, since part of my reasoning involves analyzing the meaning of other's statements, I need to know what prior information (including the rules) they have been given as well.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Just to be sure, I'm not wrong, am I?, in saying that if I ever hear someone say "I don't know" then the matter is immediately settled.  After all, the thief can never say that, so if I hear that statement then I am sure the thief is the third member.  By contrast, the statement "I do know!" is problematic and may depend on prior conversation/non-conversations.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, you are right that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does indeed appear to be some form of paradox here, but it is very subtle.

To be completely clear, I'm assuming the game proceeds in rounds. In each round, a neutral umpire randomly chooses one of the players and directs him to tell another random player whether he knows yet who the thief is. The recipient of that information then immediately makes all the inferences he can from this knowledge before the next round. The third player, who was not party to the communication does not know what was said **and does not even know a round took place**.

First off, a few simple facts: If you know you're innocent, and you hear *anyone else* say they *don't* know who the thief is, then by elimination you now know that the third person is the thief. Therefore if *you* ever tell anybody "I don't know", the only thing they *can* subsequently tell *you* is "I know who it is". So that won't make you any wiser.

Now, let us ask:

> (1) If you know you are innocent and the first thing that happens to you in the game is that someone tells you "I know who the thief is", can you conclude anything?

Of course it is possible that the person who spoke to you is the thief, so the real question is whether it is possible that he is innocent. A priori it sounds *conceivable* that the two other guys may have communicated without you noticing, such that the innocent among them now knows.

However, how could that communication go? One of them must have spoken first. If the innocent one spoke first, then (as argued above) he will never get any information out of the thief that's useful to him, so he will not end up knowing.

On the other hand,  if the *thief* spoke first, then the innocent guy would have found himself in *exactly the situation* described by (1) above. And now we're in trouble:

If the correct answer to (1) is "yes", then it is possible that the other innocent guy learned from the thief who the thief was, and therefore you can subsequently be told by *either* the thief or the other guy that they know. Therefore the correct answer to (1) is "no".

On the other hand, if the correct answer to (1) is "no", then there is no way the other innocent guy could ever know who the thief is, as long as *you* haven't communicated with either of them. And therefore if one of them admits to knowing, they must be the thief. So the correct answer to (1) is "yes".

Thus, the answer to (1) can be neither "yes" nor "no". A paradox!

---

I *think* the resolution to this is that this reasoning depends critically on the assumption that nobody ever knows whether the first communication they are part of is the first round of the game or not. That's a critical part of the argument that the answer to (1) depends on a previous answer to *the same question*.

On the other hand if somebody *knows* it's the very first round of the game when someone tells them "I know who it is", then they can comfortably conclude that they must be the thief.

And contrariwise, *therefore*, if somebody knows it's the *second* round of the game when they're told that, then they know they *can't* conclude anything.

So really what enables the paradox is the assumption that time is continuous (or at least dense): no matter how quickly after the game starts we get a message, it is in principle possible that the two other guys may already have talked.

Thus, we might categorize the paradox as a time-reversed cousin of the [surprise exam paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox).

Further, I suspect that trying to **formalize** the paradox (in some appropriate variant of temporal+epistemic logic) will run into trouble with expressing the assumption that everyone are perfect logicians, and everyone knows that everyone else are perfect logicians, and everyone knows that too, *et cetera ad infinitum*. Even defining what "perfect logic" should *mean* seems to require a powerful enough reasoning system that Gödelian incompleteness kicks in and tells us that in that case *there is no such thing* as a perfect logician, at least not one that can be reasoned about.